# make class only instantiable from specific class

Tags: java, class, modifier

Let's say I have 3 classes
`class1`, `class2` and `class3`.

How can I have it that `class1` can only get instantiated by `class2` (`class1 object = new class1()`) but not by class3 or any other class?

I think it should work with modifiers but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you need `class1` to be accessible to other classes, just not able to be instantiated?

Answer (score 2):

I want to rename your classes to `Friend`, `Shy` and `Stranger`.  The `Friend` should be able to create `Shy`, but `Stranger` should not be able to.

This code will compile:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Friend {

    public void createShy() {
        Shy shy = new Shy();
    }

    private static class Shy {

    }

}
```

But this code won't:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class Stranger {

    public void createShy() {
        Friend.Shy shy = new Friend.Shy();
    }

}
```

In addition, if we create a new class called `FriendsChild`, this **won't** compile either:

```
package com.sandbox;

public class FriendsChild extends Friend {

    public void childCreateShy() {
        Shy shy = new Shy();
    }

}
```

And this naming convention makes sense when you think about it.  Just because I'm a friend of someone doesn't mean my child knows them.

Notice that all these classes are in the same package. As far as I can understand, this is the scenario you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides making the constructor protected:

- Make the `class1` constructer private
- Make a public static factory method that requires a valid instance of `class2` inorder to return an instance of `class1`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

make `protected` constructor and put the eligible class in same package, if you want any class outside of package to construct this instance then you need that class to extend `ClassA` in this example,

if you restrict it then go for `default` access specifier

```
package com.somthing.a;
public class ClassA {

    ClassA() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}

package com.something.a;
public class ClassB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassA();//valid
    }
}


package com.something.c;
public class ClassC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassA();// invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not package-private constructor?

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  If the constructor is protected, that means a class that extends it can still call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Make class1 inner class of class2.