# How to make a single class responsible for construction of another class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm writing a class library with a class called `Application`. The `Application` class contains a collection of `Document` objects. I want the `Application` class to be solely responsible for "creating" (constructing) `Document` objects when appropriate. I do not want myself or other our developers to be able to construct new `Document` objects arbitrarily.

I've tried to come up with some robust way to enforce this, but I've only come up with a couple possibilities, and they both have drawbacks.

The first way would be to nest the `Application` class within the `Document` class, and make the `Document` constructor private such that only the `Application` class can access it. But this makes no sense structurally, and is in fact the opposite of the true relationship. Not to mention that public nested classes are generally discouraged.

The other way I tried was to make the `Document` constructor private, but give it a public "factory method" that does some checking to try and make sure it really was called by the `Application`. But this became very convoluted as I tried to implement it.

Am I over-complicating this? Surely it's a common thing for a codebase to be built such that developers *could* do something that they shouldn't? Should I just expect our developers (and myself) to use discretion and common-sense and not go around constructing new `Document` objects, when they *should* be getting them from the `Application` instead?

Or am I correct in trying to enforce this? Am I correct in my pursuit for classes to only be usable as intended? After all, this is what access levels are for in the first place -- to enforce usage of entities only in the correct context. If this is a reasonable pursuit, does anyone have any suggestions for how to do so in this circumstance?

---

Note: I found this similar thread: [java - make class only instantiable from specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366312/make-class-only-instantiable-from-specific-class). But the proposed solution was nested classes, which aren't a good option for the reasons I gave above.

Comment: You could make a new interface `IDocument` which is public, then implement it with a *private* inner `Document` class, inside `Application`?

Comment: If they are in the same project, you could make your constructor `internal`

Comment: You could move these classes into their own project and use `internal`.  This can be sidestepped with reflection and `AssemblyInfo` settings but it would be quite clear if someone was constructing them in a way you don't want.

Comment: The `Application` class shouldn't be calling a constructor anyway - it should be passed an abstract factory method that it uses to do so, although that doesn't help with your issue. However, I think you're trying to overengineer it.

Comment: All great suggestions. I'm thinking a public interface/private nested implementation may be the simplest and most appropriate. I'll mull that over for a bit.

Comment: I thought about a separate assembly, but I want to avoid adding extra projects and DLLs.

Comment: @MatthewWatson can you explain why `Application` shouldn't be calling a constructor? Also, is there a design pattern that I can reference for how to do what you're suggesting instead?

Comment: @DRoam The pattern is called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I can recommend [this book](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns?a_aid=ploeh&a_bid=844515ef) which is required reading where I work. The [author's blog](https://blog.ploeh.dk/archive/) has some interesting stuff too.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this, but it's somewhat convoluted and I wouldn't do it...

You can put the `Document` implementation in a separate assembly and make its constructor `internal`.

Then put the `Application` class in another assembly (on its own) and use [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) in the Document assembly to make the `Document` constructor visible to the `Application` assembly.

That way only code in the `Application` assembly or the `Document` assembly will be able to construct a `Document`. (Of course, this can be circumvented simply by adding classes to the `Application` assembly or the `Document` assembly that create instances of `Document`...)

Although I wouldn't actually want the `Application` class to directly create instances of `Document`. I'd want to abstract `Document` behind an `IDocument` class and pass a factory method to `Application` to use to create `IDocument` items.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do exactly what you want. What you can do is declare all constructors for the class `internal`/`Friend` and then only classes in the same assembly will be able to invoke them. It's then up to you which types declared in that assembly actually do invoke those constructors. If you want only one class to do it, only do it in that one class. That's exactly how the `DataRow` class works. Notice that you cannot create a `DataRow` object directly but you can do so indirectly, using the `DataTable.NewRow` or `DataRowCollection.Add` methods?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, C# does not provide a way for a class to restrict its methods, in this case a constructor, to only be callable from specific other classes. Nesting `Document` within `Application` and exposing it to other classes through an interface may be your best bet -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016719/how-to-create-a-constructor-that-is-only-usable-by-a-specific-class-c-friend) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is use

```
[CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = ""
```

as a param in your method (or constructor) to validate if the caller is from your Application. However, this one is still run-time error not compile error.

If you want to enforce at compile time, you need to move both classes into a project and use internal constructor for Document, and public method in Application.